# Is it MuesliSwap the only DEX with an API?

Tags: api, dex

I'd like to build a backend that brings data from all Cardano DEXes.

I have been exploring this link: https://docs.muesliswap.com/cardano/api/api-v1

Is it the only DEX that provides an API? I didn't find any information on MinSwap, SundaeSwap or Wingriders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Minswap** uses a GraphQL endpoint that you can find here:

- https://monorepo-mainnet-prod.minswap.org/graphql/

Example:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://monorepo-mainnet-prod.minswap.org/graphql/ \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"query":"query TVLSeries {  tvlSeries {    time    tvl  }}\n\n","operationName":"TVLSeries"}'
```

They also have an adapter to query their data using Blockfrost:

- https://github.com/minswap/blockfrost-adapter

**SundaeSwap** has an API located at:

- https://stats.sundaeswap.finance/api/

Example:

```
curl --request GET \
  --url https://stats.sundaeswap.finance/api/ticks/0029cb7c88c7567b63d1a512c0ed626aa169688ec980730c0473b913.70202d01/2022/09/02
```

Both of them don't seem to have public documentation, so you can either ask the team directly or try to find the endpoints you need.

Hope this helps!