# Is there a possibility to fetch the volumen of e.g Minswap with Koios or Blockfrost?

Tags: blockchain, blockfrost, api

I am looking for a way to get the volume of certain protocols on Cardano(e.g. Minswap or SundaeSwap). I thought of using Koios or Blockfrost, but I am not entirely sure how to get volume. If there's some math involved I don't have a problem.

I'm happy with any approach that might work. xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, the best way to fetch stats from specific protocols is to use their APIs or data points. You can reach out to their teams to know more about this. Discord servers seem to be a good starting point, since the majority of the Devs are there.

In the meantime, I suggest checking [this post](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/8991/is-it-muesliswap-the-only-dex-with-an-api) that already has information on some DEXes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helps a lot.